# Activex DLL throws error "Object Required"

Tags: dll, vb6

My vb6 exe is calling an Active-x dll (registered in COM+), but getting an "object required" error when the dll tries to call a method that reads SQL db.

My exe code is:

```
Set oBulkRework = New apBulkRework.BulkRework
sReturnCode = oBulkRework.BulkRework(sProductID, iQty, sUID)
Set oBulkRework = Nothing
```

My DLL code is:

```
    public Function BulkRework(ByVal psProductID As String, _
                         ByVal piQty As Long, _
                         ByVal psUID As String) As String

    Dim oReceipt As dbReceipt.Receipt
    Dim oRS_Receipt As ADODB.Recordset
    Set oReceipt = GetObjectContext.CreateInstance("dbReceipt.Receipt")
 ==> Set oRS_Receipt = oReceipt.SearchForRework(psProductID,piQty,psUID)

    Set oReceipt = Nothing
```

dbReceipt ddl does sql execute to select a collections of records.

The program is crashing at line "==>".

If I run it from the development environment, I get Err.Description = "Object Required", Err.Number = -2147164123.

If I run the exe, I get:
  Err.Descriptn = "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface"

Err.Number = 430

What am I missing? Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: What does the SearchForRework do? Do you have the code for that method?

Comment: Could you try one small change in your code? Can you change this line 
Dim oRS_Receipt As ADODB.Recordset
TO
Dim oRS_Receipt As New ADODB.Recordset

Comment: It just execute sql statement:     oCmd.CommandText = sSQL
    Set oRS = oCmd.Execute

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `CeateObject()` instead of `New` in vb6?

Comment: Tried both methods CreateObject() and New. Both give similar message.

Comment: BTW, Receipt dll has been around forever and used by many other programs, including calls from asp page.

Comment: Changed to oRS_Receipt As New ADODB.Recordset. Still same error.

Comment: In that case, I suspect some changes have been made on the Database side. The method is not able to execute the query or make a connection to the database. Can you confirm that the DLL has made a connection to the database?

Comment: Yes. Other asp pages are calling this program and working. Is there something I need to do to allow exe (outside the COM+) to access the dll in COM+?

Comment: You don't need to define anything as `New`.  The question here is where is `dbReceipt.Receipt` defined?  Is it in your COM class or an extension of your COM classes?  Or, does your COM class link to a none existent library, i.e. a library required by the class?